# Convergence / absolute convergence of alternating infinite series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can it be shown that $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{n}}{\sqrt [3]{n+1}}}$ is convergent and /or absolute convergent?

Answer (score 3):

It's convergent by the [Leibniz criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_criterion), because $\frac1{\sqrt[3]{n+1}}$ is decreasing to $0$.

And it's not absolutely convergent, because $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^\alpha}$ is divergent for $\alpha\leq1$.

Comment: The name is [*Leibniz*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gottfried_Wilhelm_Leibniz). It is pronounced  [ˈlaɪpnɪts] (*lipenits*).

Comment: @Carsten Schultz Thanks, I couldn't even see the difference until I looked at the edit diff :)

Comment: I can imagine, but they look completely different to a German. *Lieb* is pronounced [liːp] (*leap*). More to the point, monotonicity should be mentioned. I always forget that, too, since it usually is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n/\sqrt[3]{n+1}$ converges because it is alternating and the $n$th term goes to zero. But the series is not conditionally convergent: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1/\sqrt[3]{n+1}$ diverges by the $p$-test.

Comment: Instead of " conditionally" should be "absolutely".

Answer (score 1):

Absolute value of the series goes as $(n+1)^{-1/3}$, which is too slow to converge ($\sum n^a$ diverges for $a\geq -1$). This means it is not absolute convergent.

The $+1$ doesn't do anything but shifts the series by one. You just have to look up convergence criteria for sums of negative powers (they are the same as convergence criteria for integrals).

The alternating series is still convergent because the absolute values of terms decrease monotonously.